# Unable to open socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, video-streaming

I am trying to open a socket connection to a specific address using a class which extends Thread. The overridden run method code is

```java
private String headerForGetConnection() {
    return String.format(
            "GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: %s\r\nx-sessioncookie: %s\r\nAccept: application/x-rtsp-tunnelled\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\n\r\n", 
            addressAttributes(), this.USER_AGENT, this.session_cookie
    );
}

private String addressAttributes() {
    return "/img/video.sav?MAC=" + this.camera.getDevice().getMac() + "&GUID=" + "GUID value";
}

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();

    int count = 0;

    int MAX_CONNECTION_TRY = 3;
    while (count < MAX_CONNECTION_TRY && !shouldCloseConnection) {

        TCLog.d(TAG, "counting value " + count);
        count++;
        socket = null;
        bufferedInputStream = null;
        printWriter = null;

        try {
            TCLog.d(TAG, "media serverAddress " + serverAddress + " serverPort == " + serverPort);

            SocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            socket = socketFactory.createSocket(serverAddress, serverPort);
            TCLog.d(TAG, "Media server socket value after connecting to address and port == " + socket);
            if (null == bufferedInputStream) {
                bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            }

        } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
            TCLog.d(TAG, "value UnknownHostException" + e.getMessage());
            handleError(e.getMessage());
        } catch(IOException e) {
            TCLog.d(TAG, "value IOException " + e.getMessage());
            handleError(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            printWriter.println(serverHeader);
            printWriter.flush();
            isFirstMessage = true;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            TCLog.d(TAG, "value IOException while writing " + e.getMessage());
            handleError(e.getMessage());
        }

        while (!shouldCloseConnection) {
            try {
                String dataToSend = null;
                byte[] readingData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int read;
                byte[] data = null;
                if ((read = bufferedInputStream.read(readingData)) != -1) {
                    TCLog.d(TAG, "OTHER read value " + read);
                    data = Arrays.copyOfRange(readingData, 0, read);
                    dataToSend = new String(data);
                }
                if (null != dataToSend) {
                    TCLog.d(TAG, "message from server " + dataToSend);
                    if (isFirstMessage) {

                        if (!dataToSend.contains("200 OK")) {

                            if (dataToSend.contains("303")) {

                                TCLog.d(TAG, "when there is redirect");
                                TCLog.d(TAG, "splitting string value");

                                String[] videos = dataToSend.split("https://");

                                TCLog.d(TAG, "values 1 " + videos[0]);
                                TCLog.d(TAG, "value 2 " + videos[1]);

                                String redirectUrl = videos[1];

                                videos = redirectUrl.split(":");

                                redirectUrl = videos[0];

                                TCLog.d(TAG, "redirect URL is " + redirectUrl);

                                isRedirectUrl = true;

                                this.serverAddress = redirectUrl;
                                Reflector.address = this.serverAddress;
                                break;
                            } else if (dataToSend.contains("HTTP/1.0 4")) {
                                isRedirectUrl = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            this.isFirstMessage = false;
                            if (null != listener) {
                                this.listener.getConnectionConnectedSuccessfully();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (null != listener) {
                            listener.getConnectionRawData(data, dataToSend.trim());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                TCLog.d(TAG, "value IOException while reading " + e.getMessage());
                handleError(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                TCLog.d(TAG, "inside finally block");
                if (isFirstMessage && !isRedirectUrl) {
                    handleError("Unable to play video");

                    if (null != printWriter) {
                        printWriter.close();
                    }
                    try {
                        TCLog.d(TAG, "inside finally try block. Closing connections");
                        if (null != bufferedInputStream) {
                            bufferedInputStream.close();
                        }
                        if (null != socket && socket.isConnected()) {
                            socket.close();
                        }
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        TCLog.d(TAG, "error while closing streams " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!isRedirectUrl) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (count >= MAX_CONNECTION_TRY && !shouldCloseConnection) {
        handleError("Unable to establish connection");
    }
}
```

The first log (media server address) gets printed, but the 2nd log does not and my socket connection goes into limbo. No code after trying to create a socket gets executed. It is not a consistent behaviour, at-times the socket connection is successful.

If the socket connection is successful, there is a certain GET command/call that we are supposed to make.
I tried to make the GET call as an API call/REST call and every time I got a reply from the server even if there is a delay of about 10-12 seconds which makes me believe that it is not a server config issue (I might be wrong). Any insight or any suggestion on how to proceed forward?

Comment: This little snippet missing critical information making it hard to diagnose what's going on. The first thing I'd like to know is the value of `serverHeader`, and also why it's called `serverHeader` if this is a client HTTP request.